# How can I get or make a USB to SATA-power cable?

Tags: usb, sata, power, cable

I have a 2.5 inch SATA SSD that I want to power from an internal USB port.
The SSD requires 5 volts, so I see this as being possible.

I already have the data connection for the SSD, I just need to power it over USB.  I know this is possible because I have a PCMCIA card for a different machine that draws power from a USB port in this manner.

Are these types of cables already in production somewhere?  If so, where?

If they're not (I haven't found any), what would I need to do to create one?  I'm unfamiliar with how SATA power cables are wired out and don't want to fry my USB card with novice testing when I have the chance of getting insight from a SU expert.

---

Update: I don't want data travelling over USB.  As I have a SATA data cable ready for this drive, I will be mounting it in the case and running the power to an internal USB cable.

I thank all of you for your answers regarding buying an external USB case for this drive, but that's not the question I'm asking.

Comment: Typically, one would use an eSATA port to provide both power and data to the drive.  Most eSATA ports also double as a USB port.  Note that because of the power differences in laptops and desktops, laptops have limitations on what devices they can power in this manor.

Comment: @earthmeLon I have yet to see eSATA provide power. Do you have a link with information on this?

Comment: If you are mounting it inside the case, then why would you be trying to use USB power, and not pulling directly from the power supply?

Comment: Why not?  I know this is possible and this may have useful application in the future.

Comment: @earthmeLon: AFAIK, you need a Power over eSata to get enough power spin a harddrive off of one port.

Comment: The drive I'm using requires only 5v.  This should work with a normal USB port.

Comment: I have an external CD drive which uses eSATAp for data and power. It's typically called an eSATA/USB combo port and has power to it. In this situation, is there a reason you can't just use a SATA power connector from your PSU in addition to a SATA data cable? Using USB seems out of the way.

Comment: All SATA power cables are in use and I don't want to replace PSU or split them.  This is a real problem that I'm facing, and my question is about creating a cable to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see "offical" cables to do this, but there is a hardware hack here [Stealing 5V from USB](http://forums.parallax.com/entry.php?74-Stealing-5V-from...) from Parallax inc forum. If nothing else, it shows how easy or hard it is to do (depending on your specific skills) and could be a starting path for your 5v needs.