# SATA Data & Power Cable

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I want to use this Western Digital hard drive: http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0088PUEPK/ref=noref?ie=UTF8&psc=1&s=computers as a bck up for my laptop and other drives i have, I have a eSATA port on my laptop and i was wondering if this cable: 
http://www.amazon.co.uk/1-5GB-Serial-Combo-Power-Cable/dp/B000M1EB70/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top 
would power the hard drive? All i want to know is if this cable will power this drive.

Comment: I think this question might be a little too specific. I recommend you go back and figure out what you're asking. Can an internal HDD be connected to an eSATA port? Look at what you're trying to do and express the question as that, so it is more applicable to future visitors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to power a 3.5in drive from a laptop?](http://superuser.com/questions/297149/how-to-power-a-3-5in-drive-from-a-laptop)

Comment: What i want to do is connect a hard drive to my computer with a eSATA port. Could i do this with this cable? http://www.amazon.co.uk/1-5GB-Serial-Combo-Power-Cable/dp/B000M1EB70/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top

Comment: Also see [How can I get or make a USB to SATA-power cable?](http://superuser.com/questions/358180/how-can-i-get-or-make-a-usb-to-sata-power-cable)

Comment: The answer is no you cannot, eSata has a different header than Sata.  You'd also need a molex to power that.  Just buy an eSata enclosure, you can find them for <$30.

Answer (score 1):

It'd power it if you had a powered 4-pin Molex connector to plug into the white connector, which is then converted to the SATA power.

[image]

If your notebook has a 4-pin Molex power cord, I'd be EXTREMELY surprised since it's generally a Desktop PC thing. :)

Look into getting yourself [a USB HDD enclosure](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=computers&field-keywords=external%20USB%203.5%20hdd%20enclosure&rh=n:340831031,k:external%20USB%203.5%20hdd%20enclosure) for it.

Comment: But could that cable http://www.amazon.co.uk/1-5GB-Serial-Combo-Power-Cable/dp/B000M1EB70/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top be able to power that hard drive?

Comment: techie007 gave you the answer. Yes, but only if you have a connector like the one pictured to plug it into. That product is specifically for converting power supplies that do not have SATA power cables.